# concatenation of sql results from multiple rows

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Im trying to get all unique values out of two rows in a databank as a list. Using postgresql and python.

I use this sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT from,to FROM database;
```

I get this output

```
 from | to 
------+-----
 a    | b
 d    | c
 b    | a
```

And in python as: `[('a', 'b'), ('d', 'c'), ('b', 'a')]`

But i want the result:`["a", "b", "d", "c"]`

I know i can use python to get this result but is there a direct sql query for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an union and select unique elements from there:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT value
FROM (
    SELECT from AS value FROM database
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to AS value FROM database
);
```

Comment: Seams logical but i get the error: Subquery in FROM must have an alias

Comment: It is probably because FROM is a SQL keyword, you should wrap it in quotes.

Comment: That doesn't seam to be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
SELECT to AS value FROM database UNION SELECT from FROM database;
```

In postgresql the UNION operator already restricts to distinct elements if ALL is not added. The alias is used to ensure that the output table column is named "value".

Comment: That's the way all dbms's handle `UNION`.